# Locking Program non-static variable issue, and closing issue

Tags: java

I am very new to computer programming, and am trying to create a program that reads the last three letters from a user's input, then checks to see if it is the right code to unlock a virtual safe. I can't seem to get the program to close when the user inputs "1" which is supposed to be the way to exit. There is also a problem with referencing the non-static variable "lock" in a static context, is there any way around this? Thanks for any and all help.

```
/**
 * Gets the last three lettersof the user's input.
 * 
 * @author (Sean F.) 
 * @version (1.0)
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ComboInput
{
public  static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("\f");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a letter");
    System.out.print("\n");
    String input = "";
    int comboLength = 0;
    input = in.nextLine();
    input = input.substring(0,1);
    comboLength ++;
    Lock q = new Lock();
    int lock = q.getLockStatus(input);
    String close = "1";
    while (comboLength < 3){
        System.out.println("\f");
        System.out.print("Your letters being used are:");
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.print("Enter another letter or type \"1\" to exit");
        System.out.print("\n");
        String newInput = in.nextLine();
        newInput = newInput.substring(0,1);
        input = input+newInput;
        comboLength++;
    }
    while (input.length()>=3){
        while((input.substring(2)).equals(close)){           
            System.out.println("\f");
            System.out.println("You gave up, lock is still locked");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while(!((input.substring(2)).equals(close))){
            while (lock == 0){
                while (comboLength >= 3){
                    System.out.println("\f");
                    System.out.print("Your letters being used are:");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    System.out.println(input.substring(comboLength-3));
                    System.out.print("Enter another letter or type \"1\" to exit");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    String newInput = in.nextLine();
                    newInput = newInput.substring(0,1);
                    input = input+newInput;
                    comboLength++;
                    int lock2 = q.getLockStatus(input);
                    lock = lock2;
                }  
            }
            while (lock == 1){
                System.out.println("\f");
                System.out.println("Your Combination is Correct. Unlocked");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the Second Part of the program. It is a class called Lock

```
/**
 * Gives the current status of the lock
 */
public class Lock
{
private String code;
/**
 * Constructs the correct code for the lock
 */
public Lock()
{
    code = "smf";
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @return     An integer to describe whether lock is open or not
 */
public int getLockStatus(String c)
{
        if (c.equalsIgnoreCase(code)){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }       
}
```

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the code so it's not so tortured.  Eg. a System.exit(0) in a while loop doesn't make any sense.  Your error is very common, I suggest you google it.

Answer (score 0):

I sure don't see any code to exit if the user enters 1, even though the prompt says that. You can fix that by adding this code after `newInput = newInput.substring(0,1);` :

```
if (newInput.equals(close))
    System.exit(0);
```

By the way, that code has about 20 different bugs in it. I'll save you the trouble and write the code for you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComboInput {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the combination, or 1 to exit: ");
    String combo = in.readLine();
    if (combo.equals("1"))
        System.exit(0);
    if (combo.equals("smf")) 
        System.out.println("That is the correct combination. The safe is open.");
    else 
        System.out.println("Incorrect combination.");
}
```

Study this code, and find out how it works, and consider it a lesson in writing simple code.

If you insist that the `Lock` class will be used, there's just one line to change. See if you can figure it out.